# Primefaces : Can I use 2 ajax events - dateSelect and blur, for the purpose of validation?

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, calendar

New to Primefaces,JSF and StackOverflow so please forgive me if I sound naive/ignorant.

I have a p:Calendar component inside an empty datatable( cellEditor) that requires validation, using an ajax
`p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{dailyBean.checkReportList}" update=":form:timeSheet,:form:timeSheetDialog" resetValues="true"  />` enables me to open a dialog box and show a FacesContext message from the bean, but how do I go further and prevent the user from choosing the wrong value in the calendar/entering invalid data?

The user can close the dialog box, so I need a function to stop the user there by either resetting values in the component or blocking control or setting focus in the component till the user enters/chooses valid data. How do I go about this?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Dont exactly understand what you want to achive, but maybe you need to use `mask` attribute set to true. Some sample you can find here: [PF mask](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/calendar.xhtml)

Comment: No, that is not my requirement. In simple terms, I need to prevent the user from making an entry after the validation message (in this case, a pop up PF dialog) is shown. That is, if validation fails,  either - 1)  invalid value should clear 2)user should be prevented from entering anything else until the valid value is entered. Thanks